# Copy file content to another file

Tags: php

My file contains this content (1.txt):

- user.php?id=XXXXXX
- user.php?id=XXXXXX
- user.php?id=XXXXXX
- user.php?id=XXXXXX
- user.php?id=XXXXXX
- text/numbers
- user.php?id=XXXXXX
- user.php?id=XXXXXX
- and so on ...

(XXXXXX = numbers)

It's possible to take only user.php?id=XXXXXX and copy them to another file, without coping unnecessary text because file contains about 50 000 lines ?

Comment: Seems like a very simple problem. What did you try?

Comment: Yes, it is possible. Please provide some lines of your code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
<?php
    //Get all the matches from the file
    $fileContents = file_get_contents('1.txt');
    preg_match_all('/user.php\?id=[0-9]{6}/', $fileContents, $matches);

    //Output to new file
    $fh = fopen('output.txt', 'w+');
    foreach ($matches['0'] as $match) {
        fputs($fh, $match."\r\n");
    }
    fclose($fh);
?>
```

Comment: By the way, should be: $matches['0']

Answer (score 7):

```
 <?php
    $file = fopen('source.txt', 'rb');
    $newfile = fopen('target.txt', 'wb');
    while(($line = fgets($file)) !== false) {
     if(strpos($line, 'user.php') !== false) {
       fputs($newfile, $line);
     }
    }
    fclose($newfile);
    fclose($file);
  ?>
```

This code hasn't been tested, but I think it will work properly.

Comment: This will work, but since the input file is large it's not very memory efficient. It would be better to read and write from and to streams created by `fopen`, line-by-line.

Comment: I've modified it, could you help me review this code? I'm not sure about whether it contains syntax error because I typed it with my Nokia E63.

Comment: It works great now, exactly what I meant. One suggestion: add the `b` flag to the opening modes (second `fopen` parameter), the manual has a note about this: `For portability, it is strongly recommended that you always use the 'b' flag when opening files with fopen().` See the [`fopen` documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php) for the reason behind this advice.

Comment: Updated as you recommended.But 'w+b' looks a little strange, did I type it properly?

Comment: I think it looks pretty nice. Anyway, on-topic: it's the proper way to do it. By the way, I just realized that the `+` is not necessary at all, since the target only needs to be written to and not read from.

Comment: Good idea.I've edited the code again.Thank you for your valuable suggestions.That's the best thing I've met today.

Answer (score -1):

```
<?php   
error_reporting(0);
$fs=fopen("1.txt", "r");
$ft=fopen("2.txt", "w");

if ($fs==NULL)
{
    echo "Can't Open Source File ...";
    exit(0);
}

if ($ft==NULL)
{
    echo "Can't Open Destination File ...";
    fclose ($fs);
    exit(1);
}

else
{
    while ($ch=fgets($fs))
        fputs($ft, $ch);

    fclose ($fs);
    fclose ($ft);
}

//echo "File Handling successfully ...";
?>
```

Comment: Simply posting a code snippet does not adequately answer the question. Consider adding an explanation of how your code solves the problem.

Answer (score -1):

**suppose you want to copy the contents of "abc.php" file to "working_file.php"
place the following code in working_file.php , it will simply copy all the content.**

```
 <div>
       <?php
        $file = fopen("abc.php", "r") or die("Unable to open file!");
        echo fread($myfile,filesize("abc.php"));
        fclose($file); 
        ?>
</div>
```